# Format JSON Array format to another JSON Array format

Tags: arrays, json

Here is the my JSON Array format

```
[
    [
        "1234",
        [
            "Name11"
        ],
        "4567",
        [
            "Name12"
        ],
        "7890",
        [
            "Name13"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "1234",
        [
            "Name21"
        ],
        "4567",
        [
            "Name22"
        ],
        "7890",
        [
            "Name23"
        ]
    ]
]
```

The "1234","4567" and "7890" are my Ids and "Name11","Name12", "Name13", "Name21", "Name22" and "Name23" are the values for each corresponding Ids.
The JSON array contains two records as shown above. Now i need to convert the following JSON Format....

```
[
    {
        "1234":"Name11",
        "4567":"Name12",
        "7890":"Name13"
    },
    {
        "1234":"Name21",
        "4567":"Name22",
        "7890":"Name23"
    }
]
```

Please help me out, how can i construct the above mentioned JSON array format.

Comment: It is in Java Script

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript:

```
var src = [
    [
        "1234",
        [
            "Name11"
        ],
        "4567",
        [
            "Name12"
        ],
        "7890",
        [
            "Name13"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "1234",
        [
            "Name21"
        ],
        "4567",
        [
            "Name22"
        ],
        "7890",
        [
            "Name23"
        ]
    ]
]

var newObj = []
for(var i = 0; i< src.length; i++){
  var item = {}
  for(var j = 0; j<src[i].length; j++){
     if(j%2 === 0){
       item[src[i][j]] = ""
     }else{
       item[src[i][j-1]] = src[i][j][0]
     }
  } 
  newObj.push(item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following code (see the snippet below):

```
var res = src.map(function(a){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=0;i<a.length/2;i++) {
         var item = {};
         item[a[i*2]] = a[i*2+1][0]; 
         arr.push(item);   
     };
     return arr;
});
```

```js
var src = [
[
    "1234",
    [
        "Name11"
    ],
    "4567",
    [
        "Name12"
    ],
    "7890",
    [
        "Name13"
    ]
],
[
    "1234",
    [
        "Name21"
    ],
    "4567",
    [
        "Name22"
    ],
    "7890",
    [
        "Name23"
    ]
]
];

var res = src.map(function(a){
var arr = [];
for(var i=0;i<a.length/2;i++) {
   var item = {};
   item[a[i*2]] = a[i*2+1][0]; 
   arr.push(item);   
};
return arr;
});

document.getElementById("res").textContent = JSON.stringify(res);
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```